# Is there a way to allow certain code to continuously run after the app has been TERMINATED?

Tags: ios

Right now, I am developing an alarm app and I have everything done, it being able to ring at a certain time in the background, being able to set the alarm, etc. All I need left is the notification, as well as being able to run the app while being terminated, if able to do so. I've been trying to research how other apps do this while being terminated instead of in the background. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When an app is terminated, it is terminated.  What actions do you want taken?  You could probably set a scheduled task on the user's system that will have the app run and perform the necessary task.

Comment: For an alarm app, you can send the user local notification. This is somewhat limited, but you can do that.

Comment: @appsecguy when the app is terminated, I still want the alarm to be able to go off.

Comment: Hm, a point to consider is that the user terminated the app because they *don't* want the alarm to go off or the app to run.  If you want an alarm to go off anyway, I'd recommend a one-time scheduled task

Comment: @appsecguy sorry to change the topic on you, but now for some reason I cant even get the alarm to sound when the app is in the background. In the simulator it works just fine, but when i run the app on my phone from xcode, the background sound doesn't go off at the desired time? Would you know how I would go about this??